# SHIFT-F6 as menu shortcut

Tags: d, gtkd

In my current code I have the code

```
MenuItem runFileItem = new MenuItem(
  (MenuItem mi) => pm.runFile(), 
  "_Run file", 
  "activate", true, accelGroup, 'r',
  ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK | ModifierType.SHIFT_MASK, 
  AccelFlags.VISIBLE);
```

which works as expected - I can execute the handler pm.runFile() by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+r. Reason why I did it this way is because I could not figure out how to implement the preferred SHIFT+F6 that I wanted to use for this purpose. It would be good if I could put GDK_F6 GDK Keysym (from the `gdk.Keysyms` module), but could not find a way to use it. I've also asked the same question on GtkD forum (https://forum.gtkd.org/groups/GtkD/thread/2976/) without luck.

So the question is how to modify the above code to make SHIFT+F6 combination be handled properly as originally planned?

UPDATE:
Based on Adam's answer, the following code works:

```
MenuItem runFileItem = new MenuItem("_Run file", (MenuItem mi) => pm.runFile(), "activate");
runFileItem.addAccelerator("activate", accelGroup, GdkKeysyms.GDK_F6, ModifierType.SHIFT_MASK, AccelFlags.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constructor you're calling: https://api.gtkd.org/gtk.MenuItem.MenuItem.this.3.html

Forwards some of its arguments to this function on the base class:

https://api.gtkd.org/gtk.Widget.Widget.addAccelerator.html

Notice the ctor takes `char` but that other function takes `uint` so it should be able to take more values.

So I'd suggest trying:

```
auto mi = new MenuItem(label, action);
mi.addAccelerator(
  "activate", accelGroup, GDK_F6,
  ModifierType.SHIFT_MASK, 
  AccelFlags.VISIBLE
);
```

and see if it works.

Comment: It worked with few tiny changes: `MenuItem runFileItem = new MenuItem("_Run file", (MenuItem mi) => pm.runFile(), "activate"); runFileItem.addAccelerator("activate", accelGroup, GdkKeysyms.GDK_F6, ModifierType.SHIFT_MASK, AccelFlags.VISIBLE);`